# Conversion from varchar to Datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion, varchar

I have a date field with varchar data type and some of the values are for example 20220101000009CS.
I need to show date as (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') and tried the below query but getting the error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

```sql
select convert(datetime, 'DATE',20) 
from [TABLE1].[dbo].[ABC]
```

Please advice how do I get around this.

Comment: What date and time does `'20220101000009CS'` represent? What does the "CS" mean? Why are you not storing your date and time data as a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes)?

Comment: Side note, `convert(datetime, 'DATE',20) ` is *never* going to work. `DATE` is a literal string here, not a reference to a column called `date`.

Comment: I just used the word Date to represent the field which has varchar data type. 20220101000009CS can be broken to 2020 01 01 00 00 00 CS (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss) stands for central time. Its a legacy database where the data type is varchar.

Comment: So can the CS be ignored? Are there other timezones? If so, does the value need to actually be converted to a `datetimeoffset`..? If so, CS isn't a standard name for the timezone, so we need to know what other values there are. Do these values need to consider for DST?

Comment: CS can be ignored and there are no other time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` to inject the needed characters in the right place to get the format `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss` which is also unambiguous in SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT V.YourColumn,
       CONVERT(datetime2(0),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(V.YourColumn,14),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
FROM (VALUES('20220101000009CS'))V(YourColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    SUBSTRING(datefield, 1, 4),
    SUBSTRING(datefield, 5, 2),
    SUBSTRING(datefield, 7, 2),
    SUBSTRING(datefield, 9, 2),
    SUBSTRING(datefield, 11, 2),
    SUBSTRING(datefield, 13, 2),
    0)
FROM [TABLE1].[dbo].[ABC];
```